# Javascript cannot return values

Tags: javascript

I want to get the values a, b, c from these functions and use them in my total. I have tried to return the values but it doesn't work. When I create global variables, total always takes the original global variable instead of the one from the function.

```
function d1() {
  var a = document.getElementById("s1").value;
  document.getElementById("d1").innerHTML = (2 * a).toFixed(2);
  return a;
}

function d2() {
  var b = document.getElementById("s2").value;
  document.getElementById("d2").innerHTML = (3 * b).toFixed(2);
  return b;
}

function d3() {
  var c = document.getElementById("s3").value;
  document.getElementById("d3").innerHTML = (4 * c).toFixed(2);
  return c;
}

var total = a + b + c;
document.getElementById("total").innerHTML = total.toFixed(2);
```

Comment: Value of variables is never manipulated...

Comment: a, b and c are not visible outside their functions.

Comment: You should be doing `var total = d1() + d2() + d3()`

Comment: you did not call those functions in your code here. try `var total = d1() + d2() + d3();`

Comment: please accept my [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39695537/2545680) if it helped you.

Answer (score 3):

I think it should be

```
var total = d1() + d2() + d3();
```

Since variables a, b and c are local to the functions and they fall into those functions scope. However, the biggest problem is that you do not call the functions at all, so even with using global variables your a,b,c would be undefined.

Answer (score 1):

a, b and c are local variables within d1, d2 and d3 respectively. So, you can't use them directly outside of their scope like you have tried to.

There are multiple ways of achieving your desired outcome. The easiest

```
function d1() {
            var a = document.getElementById("s1").value;
            document.getElementById("d1").innerHTML = (2*a).toFixed(2);
            return a;
            }

            function d2() {
            var b = document.getElementById("s2").value;
            document.getElementById("d2").innerHTML = (3*b).toFixed(2);
            return b;
            }

            function d3() {                 
            var c = document.getElementById("s3").value;
            document.getElementById("d3").innerHTML = (4*c).toFixed(2);
            return c;
            }

            **var total = d1() + d2() + d3();**
            document.getElementById("total").innerHTML = total.toFixed(2);
```